# iOS show activity indicator and text connecting in navigationItem title?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im trying to show a activity indicator along with the text "connecting" in the `navigationItem.titleView`.

I've managed to the the activity indicator to show but not the text.

My current code:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = nil;

UIActivityIndicatorView *aiView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
aiView.hidesWhenStopped = NO;
self.navigationItem.titleView = aiView;
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Try below...

```
// first create main view
UIView *mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:.....

// now lets create label that you need to display
UILabel *titleLabel  = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:.....
titleLabel.text = @"Title here";
[mainView addSubview:titleLabel];

// now create indicator
UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = initWithFrame:.....
[mainView addSubview:indicator];


// now add mainView to titleView
self.navigationItem.titleView = mainView;
```